# Connection between VM and another computer (Ethernet cable)

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, ethernet, ping

As the title says, I am trying to communicate with one VM and another computer connected via Ethernet cable. I can't ping each other do you have any idea? (VirtualBox) I have "bridge network" on the VirtualBox configuration.

```
IP Virtual Machine:  192.168.128.73 Mask 255.255.255.240

Differents network on host machine : 
Carte Ethernet vEthernet (Default Switch) :
IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.128.65
Mask. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
default gateway. . . . . . . . . : 169.254.0.0


Carte Ethernet VirtualBox Host-Only Network :

   
   IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 10.18.1.17
   Mask. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default gateway. . . . . . . . . :


Carte Ethernet Ethernet 
Activated when Ethernet Cable is on and link to the other computer.




IP Address to the computer I want to ping (via Ethernet Cable) ;
10.X.Y.3
```

Comment: what's the IP of the other machine? Its pretty clear they're on different networks - so how you have set up the rest of the network would be important

Comment: "Carte Ethernet VirtualBox Host-Only Network :"  Host-Only isolates the machine. Change this to "Bridged" and get the Host IP address range.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the IP of the other PC (connected via ethernet)  is 10.X.Y.3

Comment: Did you change away from Host-Only ?

Comment: Your VM is on a 192.168.x28.x range... your other PC is on a 10.x.y.3 range - unless you have routing set up between the two ranges somewhere, you shouldn't be able to reach one from the other.

Comment: @John I already put my virtualmachine in bridge mode , I can ping the "Ethernet Ethernet" but not the other PC from my VM , maybe it's the firewall ?  or should i change Gateway + IP of my Host PC or VM ?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I did change to 10.X.Y.3 my VM but when i do that my VM cant even ping the Host computer where it is

Comment: Hence me wondering about the network as a whole. And what OS does the phyical machine run? Windows blocks ping by default IIRC

Comment: I am looking around. "Bridged" should work. I am working in a Kali Linux machine, NAT networking, VMware Workstation. Default Firewalls and default router gateway. Ping, Folder mapping all work. So I am still looking.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The Host machine is on windows (normally , not sure , i put down the firewall thing) , my VM is Ubuntu , the Other PC connected via Ethernet is Windows

Comment: @John so for you i dont even need to change my IP or Mask or default gateway to connect each other since i'm in bridge ?

Comment: Here, no.   Connections, firewall and such are all default.