# How do I access a computer connected to the VM host via ethernet cable from a virtualbox VM?

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ethernet

So I want to be able to ping Host2 from inside the Virtual Machine. Right now, I can ping Host2 from the host, but Host2 does not respond when pinged from within the virtual machine. I have virtualbox configured in NAT mode. I can ping google.com from within the virtual machine, so it does have internet access using NAT. The connection between Host2 and the Host is an ethernet cable plugged into both machines. I also tried using the bridge adapter configuration for virtualbox but that didn't seem to make Host2 visible to the VM over ssh. Note that I cannot connect Host2 to the WIFI router, since it is outside of my control. If it's helpful, the Host Operating system is windows 10. I have provided a diagram to show my network layout; this should ideally work with or without the connection between the host and the wifi router being enabled.

[network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPVqB.png)

This is similar to [Connection between VM and another computer (Ethernet cable)](https://superuser.com/questions/1637886/connection-between-vm-and-another-computer-ethernet-cable) but I think a slight difference is that in this case this needs to work with and without the host being connected to a router, and I'm not sure how bridged adapter mode works without the host being connected to a local network.

Comment: Use a [packet capture tool](https://www.wireshark.org/) to check where the pings (ICMP Echo) or ssh connection attempts (TCP SYN packets) go and where the replies go.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this, using this [how do I ssh from a vm to a private server through an ethernet cable?](https://superuser.com/questions/966595/how-do-i-ssh-from-a-vm-to-a-private-server-through-an-ethernet-cable) advice. Basically the key is that you need to set the mode to bridged adapter *and* set the network for the bridged adapter to the Ethernet link instead of the Wifi card. Hopefully this comes in handy for people who are trying to get VirtualBox VMs to connect over link-local network.

Comment: It also works through NAT.  Maybe it's a DNS or similar naming problem.